# Eclipse how to add a widget to an existing Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, widget

I have a project that I am almost done with. One thing left that I want to do is add a widget to the project. I see lots of tutorials on creating widgets, but what I don't see is how to add a widget to an existing project. They all start off with "create a new project and call it MyFirstWidget". The bottom line is I want to be able to download one package and have that include the main app and the widgets. What do I do in eclipse to get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [App Widgets developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) at android.com seems to do a good job of explaining how to implement a widget, and it's not specific to creating a new project.